# Find element after page reload

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Ok this one got me hitting my head on the wall for a while now. 
I look at a list of web elements. I access that list like so

```
foreach (IWebElement link in driver.FindElementsByCssSelector("span.cn.mailbox > a"))
        {
              // Click at a lot of page and the page will reload eventually
        }
```

The problem is, inside the loop, I need to change pages and stuff but at the end I get back to that page that has the link list. 
As soon as I hit the second iteration, I get the following error :

> [image]

Probably because I changed page and even thought the links in the collection I loop through are the same, the compiler doesn't seem to think it's the exact same collection.

Is there a way around this or a workaround I could use ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the exception is because the page the driver.FindElementsByCssSelector is referencing has been reloaded.

Something like this should work:
Create an array of link text.  Iterate through the link text array, clicking each link.

```
string [] links = new string[driver.FindElementsByCssSelector("span.cn.mailbox > a").Count);

int i = 0;
foreach (IWebElement link in driver.FindElementsByCssSelector("span.cn.mailbox > a"))
{
    links[i++] = link.Text;
}

for (int i = 0; i < driver.FindElementsByCssSelector("span.cn.mailbox > a").Count; i++)
{
   driver.FindElementByLinkText(links[i]).Click();
}
```